# Why is IOptionsMonitor<T>.OnChange not being called?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core-3.1

I'd like to have my .Net Core 3.1 app automatically reload its configuration as the file changes on disk, but I'm having trouble getting this to work with the Options pattern. I run my app, save changes to the config file, and it's never called. Why doesn't the IOptionsMonitor instance ever call the OnChange handler? What am I missing?

**Program.cs IHostBuilder creation**

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => configuration = config.Build())
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
        var separateConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("SeparateConfig.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        services
            .AddSingleton<MyMainService>()
            .Configure<MySeparateConfig>(c => separateConfig.Bind(c));
    })
```

**Service that uses MySeparateConfig**

```cs
public class MyMainService
{
    public MyMainService(IOptionsMonitor<MySeparateConfig> config)
    {
        if (config is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));

        ConfigChangeHandle = config.OnChange(UpdateConfiguration);
        
        // Perform initial configuration using config.CurrentValue here
    }

    private IDisposable ConfigChangeHandle { get; set; }
    
    private void UpdateConfiguration(MySeparateConfig config)
    {
        // Never called
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the separate config in a specific section? Why calling `Bind`? Either pass the specific section or pass the `IConfiguration`. `Bind` does not do what you think it does based on the shown code.

Comment: @Nkosi that part is working correctly, though. The config instance is populated correctly when it's injected (using `CurrentValue`). Doesn't `Bind` fill the instance's properties?

Comment: Yes, bind fills/populates the instance, I'll have to confirm if that also monitors changes.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the help - I did in fact need to pass the whole IConfiguration in as an argument instead of my `Bind` lambda, which solved my problem. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No worries. Put what worked for you as a self answer so it can help other in the future who may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Nkosi pointed out in comments, this line was the problem:

```cs
    // Wrong
    .Configure<MySeparateConfig>(c => separateConfig.Bind(c));
```

When I replaced it with the line below, everything started working right:

```cs
    // Right
    .Configure<MySeparateConfig>(separateConfig);
```

Comment: I had trouble finding this, so if anyone else can't find this, it's in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` package.

Answer (score 6):

For the reload mechanism to work with `IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>`, an `IOptionsChangeTokenSource<TOptions>` needs to be registered in the services.

If you need an `OptionsBuilder<TOptions>`, for example to add validation, this can be achieved with `AddOptions` + `BindConfiguration` (from the [Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/) NuGet package if you don't have a dependency in ASP.NET Core)

```
services.AddOptions<MyConfig>().BindConfiguration("").Validate(…)
```

Note that the `BindConfiguration` extensions method [automatically registers](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.9/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/src/OptionsBuilderConfigurationExtensions.cs#L73) the `IOptionsChangeTokenSource<TOptions>` which is the magic required for the reload mechanism to work.

Comment: Saved the day, how comes IOptionsChangeTokenSource is not even mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?!